# how to combine 2 SQL tables

Tags: php, sql

I am lost with `INNER` or `CROSS` join.

I have 2 tables, table Servers holds all info about my game servers and I get data with;

```
SELECT serverId, hlstats_Servers.name, address, port FROM hlstats_Servers
```

Table is called Livestats that holds info about the players and on what server_id they are playing. on that table I use;

```
SELECT count(steam_id) FROM hlstats_Livestats WHERE steam_id!="bot" GROUP BY server_id
```

that gives me total amount players per `server_id`

No what I want is to display a table on my website that gets server info from table Servers and puts the total amount player in front of it from table Livestats. Also if a server has no players active it should display 0

Can somebody point me in the right direction how to achive this, after 4 hours of trying I am lost.

Ok all works with the solution of  mattgiltaji (many thanks)
the typo was "ON s.serverId = l.serverId" that had to be "ON s.serverId = l.server_id" but now I run into a php problem how do I echo the COUNT(l.steam_id) ?

```
echo "<td>" . $row['steam_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['act_map'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . ':' . $row['port'] . "</td>";
```

All works except the steam_id count

FIXED thanks to Riley, I added "AS LiveStatCount" to my sql query and used that.

Comment: So you know how to get your server info, as indicated by your first query. And you know how to get counts of players per server, as indicated by your second query. So where exactly are you getting stuck? Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, LEFT JOIN will get you server with or without stat:

```
SELECT s.serverId,
       s.name,
       s.address,
       s.port,
       COUNT(l.steam_id)
FROM hlstats_Servers s
LEFT JOIN hlstats_Livestats l ON s.serverId = l.serverId
WHERE l.steam_id != "bot"
GROUP BY s.serverId,
         s.name,
         s.address,
         s.port;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT serverId, hlstats_Servers.name, address, port, count(HL.steam_id)
FROM hlstats_Servers
LEFT JOIN hlstats_Livestats HL ON serverId = HL.server_id
WHERE HL.steam_id !="bot" 
GROUP BY HL.server_id
```

Comment: This will not work; mostly it will error out saying, you are not including other columns in `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would be a [left (or right) outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join), rather than an inner or cross join.

An inner join will only return records that are in both hlstats_Servers and hlstats_Livestats,  so if you use an inner join, any servers with 0 players will not show up in the result set.

A cross join will return a combination of every row in hlstats_Servers with every row in hlstats_Livestats, which is much more data than you need.

A left (or right) outer join will return all the records that are in both tables as well as a NULL for any records that don't exist in the second table.

Your SQL might look something like this:

```
SELECT s.serverId, s.name, s.address, s.port, COUNT(l.steam_id) FROM hlstats_Servers s    
LEFT JOIN hlstats_Livestats l ON s.serverId = l.server_id AND l.steam_id != "bot"
GROUP BY s.serverId, s.name, s.address, s.port;
```

Comment: Except for 1 typo this worked as a charm since it also returned 0 value's for empty servers, the other two suggestions did not.

Comment: what was the typo? I'd be happy to edit the SQL for posterity.

Comment: the typo was "ON s.serverId = l.serverId" that had to be "ON s.serverId = l.server_id" but now I run into a php problem how do I echo the COUNT(l.steam_id) ? 

echo "<td>" . $row['steam_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['act_map'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . ':' . $row['port'] . "</td>";
All works except the steam_id count

Comment: Alias the COUNT(l.steam_id) in the SQL so you can refer to it using that name in PHP-- `COUNT(l.steam_id) AS LiveStatCount`.